# Environment import in Angular

Tags: angular, import

I'm trying to import Angular environment.ts into a different module from the app.module, specifically:

- src (Folder)

  - app (Folder)

    - Service (Folder)

      - **service.module.ts** (File) <-This is where I want to import the environment
    - app.module.ts (File)
  - environment (Folder)

    - **environment.ts** (File) <- File which I want to import

Inside app.module this works fine:

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
```

Which doesn't work inside the service.module, I have also tried:

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
```

Any ideas of how can I make this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your depiction of the filesystem, you need to go back up one more level.

Try `import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to firstly navigate two folder parent. and after navigate your prefered location

`../../environments/environment` ..

Answer (score 0):

You have to back out 2 directories and then up to `environment` or `environments`. *I am not sure because you have it spelled both ways (`environment` in your tree structure and `environments` in the paths you have tested so far)*

```
import { environment } from './../../environment/environment';
```

or

```
import { environment } from './../../environments/environment';
```

Also if you are sure the path is correct but you can't import `environment` then you might not have prefixed the class with `export`.